# having trouble showing table rows on click of table row

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a table that has groups of three rows quest_row, quest_image and quest_text. initially, only quest_row is visible - this works. It shows the question number. When the user clicks in the quest_row row of the table, I want it to show the next quest_image and quest_text row. here is the code:

```
<table width="90%">
<tr>
    <td>Questions <?php echo "how many = $how_many"; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php 
for ($i=1;$i<=$how_many;$i++) {
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);?>
<table name="quest_info" id="quest_info" border=1 width="100%">
    <tr class="quest_row">
        <td bgcolor="#00CCFF">
        Question# <?php echo $i; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php if ($row["image"] <> NULL) { ?>
        <tr class="quest_image" >
            <td class="quest_image" id="quest_image<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <img src="<?php $pic = $row['image']; echo $base_path . $pic; ?>" width="200" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="quest_text" >
            <td class="quest_text" id="quest_text<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $row["question"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
        <tr class="quest_image" >
            <td class="quest_image" id="quest_image<?php echo $i; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="quest_text" >
            <td class="quest_text" id="quest_text<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $row["question"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php 
} ?>
<?php
}  ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".quest_text").hide();
$(".quest_image").hide();
$("#quest_info").click(function(){
    var trigger = event.target;
    alert('target = ' + target);
    if(trigger.className == 'quest_row') 
    {
            $(trigger).closest('tr').next('quest_image').show();
            $(trigger).closest('tr').next('quest_text').show();
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Not sure why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has issues when showing/hiding table rows.. Try using DIV's

Comment: But I have used it before and I have seen the nearly the exact process used on many jsfiddle examples.

Comment: See if it works with DIV's and if it does then it is your tables that isnt working with JQuery.

I remember when i was doing something similar a while ago i had trouble with hiding table rows, but i switched to divs and all went fine.

Comment: so, put divs in the tr elements?

Comment: or wrap the tr elements in a div?

Comment: First just for testing make a new div like this

`<div class="mydiv"></div>`

Then use your JQuery to hide that div (just to see if it works)

`$(".mydiv").hide();`